# Changing storyboard segue arrows "style"

Tags: objective-c, xcode, segue

I'm working with different views and a lot of segue on my projet, some views having segues to a different next views and previous views.

I'll keep this short introduction simple, nothing more needs to be said. But i'm having a lot of trouble "seeing" all my arrows because of their silly graphic layout in XCode. They just always start from the right side and land on the left side, and do curves everywhere. When i've got 4 views with 3 segue each, it just gets really messy, even if I put them far from each other (because all the segue reach and start from the same point).

Is there any way to change that? I've looked on the internet but i only get tutorials on how to use segue and not really what i'm looking for. And i couldn't find anything in the preferences.

Any idea? suggestions? solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing you can do directly about the graphical representation of a storyboard and its segues. But if your storyboard is getting messy, use multiple storyboards, each containing just a few view controllers. It's easy and keeps things a lot simpler. Or use a mixture of storyboards and xibs, or even no storyboard at all (they didn't always exist; we had to use xibs for everything).